# Notification every day at a specific time

Tags: java, android, time, notifications, alarmmanager

I want to display a notification for the users of my app every day at a specific time. Maybe at 1pm. So how do I do this? I know, with an AlarmManager or Calender. But how?

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("TEST")
                    .setContentText("Benachrichtigung");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html). there's a downloadable sample too. The alarm survives reboots, so, it's just perferct. Modify it to your needs, it's not so hard to.

Comment: You can integrate it with this Notifications [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a sample app about the Alarm Manager. You can take a look it from [here](https://github.com/osayilgan/samples/tree/master/SampleApp). What you need to do basically is, push notification whenever you receive an alarm in alarm receiver Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: Wow, big app. Is it possible to just integrate the AlarmManager to my mainActivity?

Comment: Yes, all you need is AlarmReceiver. Here how it works, you add the alarm to the alarm manager, and when you receive the alarm you push a notification.